# Shall I start my example with "for example"?

Tags: writing, writing-style

I'm trying to give an example in my research paper. The first variant:

> Example 4.6. For example, this expression is true: ...

The second one:

> Example 4.6. This expression is true: ...

Which one is preferred?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since each example is labelled as such and numbered, there’s no need to further prefix the text with *For example*, and the second form is certainly preferred. That is, avoid obvious redundancies.

Use *For example* for inline non-numbered examples only.